# Does GCC have a way to specify whether to inline at the call site?

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, g++, inline

GCC has function attributes always_inline, noinline, and flatten which let you control inlining behavior when defining a function. I'm wondering if there is a way to customize inlining behavior *where the function is called*, rather than setting a global inlining behavior for it like the attributes normally do.

For noinline, I can wrap a call inside a lambda with the noinline attribute and call the lambda immediately. For flatten I can wrap the function inside a template function that has true/false specializations that call the underlying function, one with flatten and one without.

But for always_inline I have no such hack. Does one exist? To be clear, I'm looking to be able to say that a specific call to `f()` should be inlined, not cause it to always be inlined everywhere.

Comment: Any reason not to consider this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571593/how-can-i-inline-a-particular-function-call ?  If the problem is that that question didn't attract a helpful answer, you can offer a bounty on it (but FWIW I suspect GCC simply doesn't support this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the original function as inline with attribute `always_inline`, and then define another function with attribute `noinline` which calls the former (or without `noinline` if you want to still allow inlining). Call the first function when you want the call to be inlined, otherwise call the second function.

Example ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/cSD4HC)):

```
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__((always_inline))
inline void function_inlined()
{
    puts("Hello");
}

__attribute__((noinline))
void function()
{
    return function_inlined();
}

void test()
{
    function_inlined();
    function();
}
```