# __forceinline in Embedded C

Tags: c, embedded, inline, c11

Can we use __forceinline type in Embedded programming through C11?

I tried with the following syntax for

```
__forceinline static void RamPost(void);
```

But end up getting the error naming-
"this declaration has no storage class or type specifier"

Any idea where I'm wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(How) Can I inline a particular function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571593/how-can-i-inline-a-particular-function-call)

Comment: Can you clarify, which compiler are you using exactly?

Answer (score 4):

Forced inlining in the embedded programming is a very handy tool. It is much safer than than macros (type checking, normal C syntax etc etc).

Most of the compilers have extensions to force inlining (or ban it).

1. `gcc` family compilers (clang, icc ...)

in `gcc` the most common way is to use `__attribute__((always_inline))`

2. Microsoft C++ compiler extension is `__forceinline`
3. IAR : `#pragma inline = forced`
4. Keil: `__attribute__((always_inline))` and `__forceinline`
5. GH: as far as I remember `__attribute__((always_inline))`
6. Mplab XCx C compiler `__attribute__((always_inline))`

Comment: Thank you for the segregated compiler specific answer for using inline keyword .

Comment: "It is much safer than than macros". Maybe. https://godbolt.org/z/xvcrh5

Comment: @Lundin macros are prone to many prblems like here: https://godbolt.org/z/sGWTz3

Comment: Sure, macros _are_ of course flawed in many ways. But so are functions, C is far from a type safe language. It's not just a matter of reading compiler warnings, C has a tendency to merrily accept anything that can get boiled down to an `int`. For example the function in my example would also accept `char`, `short` and `long` etc and do so cleanly without any warnings. Same thing while feeding a signed negative number to a function expecting an unsigned number or vice versa. These problems could actually have been prevented with a type safe macro.

Comment: The answer shows one reason why it is a bad idea - it gets complicated if you need your code to build for multiple targets and compilers.  The solution is much worse then the problem - though the real problem is perhaps the _premature optimisation_ implied by thinking you can make better decisions about what and when to inline than the compiler.

Comment: @Clifford in embedded world portability is not the main problem.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland : You are teaching grandma to suck eggs.  It is a broad domain - you do not speak for _all_ the _embedded world_.  In 30 years of embedded development I have frequently reused code across projects and compilers.  Even if not building cross-target code, often there is still a need to _port_ code (in the sense of modifying it for a specific platform), and the less of this sort of thing, the easier that task will be.  I support this answer as nicely comprehensive BTW - the first line is however perhaps unnecessary comment/opinion that could have been omitted however.

Answer (score 1):

`__forceinline` is not standard C, so you can only rely on it if your compiler supports it.

The only fully portable way to force inlining is to use macros instead of functions. So instead of:

```
int add(int a, int b) { return a+b; }
```

you can write:

```
#define add(a,b) ((a)+(b))
```

However, this can make debugging much more complicated, and it's much easier to introduce bugs. So avoid it if possible.

Comment: £macros and inline functions have nothing in common except calling syntax. And this answer does not address the question.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland Added a line for completeness. Macros have their drawbacks, but it can be a viable workaround for OP.

Comment: No - very error prone workaround. I rather advice to avoid function like macros at any price.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland That's why I wrote *"However, this can make debugging much more complicated, and it's much easier to introduce bugs. So avoid it if possible."*

Comment: as of now Macro is not used for our requirement . Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

`__forceinline` isn't standard C, but some compiler-specific non-standard extension (Keil?). The compiler is telling you just that - it doesn't know what the keyword does since it isn't valid C.

Generally, the compiler is much more capable than the programmer in determining what to inline, why the standard `inline` keyword is mostly an obsolete feature nowadays (just like `register`).

There's very few cases where you actually need to enforce inlining. For the rare case when you do, you should probably have done the inlining by hand, possibly in assembler, or perhaps through a function-like macro. Function-like macros are generally to be avoided, but they are less worse practice than non-standard keywords IMO.

Comment: I agree to all but your assement of the usefulness of `inline` and `register`. In particular `inline` is a very valuable feature since it allows to have function definitions in header files that otherwise would result in multiple definitions in every translation unit that includes the header.

Comment: `__forceinline` seems to be used by Microsoft and ARM compilers also

Comment: *"is mostly an obsolete feature"* - Especially since they have always only been recommendations.

Comment: @JensGustedt if actually does 'static' in this case.

Comment: `inlining by hand, possibly in assembler` @Lundin why? What is wrong (in the embedded world especially) with forced inlining when necessary? Hew did not ask about your opinion about the inlining, only about the code he did not understand.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland Because forced inlining is kind of like ordering a pepperoni pizza without pepperoni. If you never want the function to be a function, then why did you make it that way? This in turn suggests problematic bigger picture issues in the program design. If the function you wish inlined is local to the same translation unit as the caller, then it will almost certainly get inlined if it makes sense to inline it. If it isn't local, then again there is something fishy with the overall program design.

Comment: @Lundin To be fair, a VERY valid reason is that you want to avoid BOTH code duplication and unnecessary function calls.

Comment: @klutt Except if you call the function multiple times from all over the same translation unit, inlining might not be such a good idea after all, since that would bloat the executable size drastically. Which in turn is a very valid concern in embedded systems where flash is limited.

Comment: @Lundin I would rather say that your answer and comments are your personal opinion not the technical answer. ***`This in turn suggests problematic bigger picture issues in the program design`***. Leave the project architecture to the actual programmers (but of course you know better what is good for them) and do not judge what is the problem or not.

Comment: @Lundin OP does not ask our opinion about inlining. You answer IMO is 100% off topic

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland That's not how engineering works. If I were a carpenter and a fellow carpenter asks me for the best way to drive in a screw with a hammer, then I'd tell them to consider a screwdriver instead. Rather than go suggesting different brands of hammers to them.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, that's a thing to consider, but it does not make my point invalid. I'm just saying that valid use cases exist.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland Relax a little bit. Just because OP has not asked for opinions about inlining does not make it a bad idea to explain a bit about them. That can be useful for both OP and future readers. And the fact that OP didn't state something like "I know about the drawbacks" is an indicator that OP is not aware of them.

Comment: ***`different brands of hammers to them`***. No comment .... Ask compiler designers to remove those extensions.

Answer (score 0):

The `__` prefix indicates that it is a compiler specific keyword and not standard C.  Consult your compiler documentation.  It will most likely have a means of forcing inline through compiler switch, `#pragma` or `__attribute__` or it may simply guarantee to inline anything marked `inline`.

Comment: Yeah Correct !! I'm Using IAR so through #prgma we can do that in our code.Thanks