# C++ Expand certain macros before others

Tags: c++, macros

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 5

#define unroll1(expr) expr();
#define unroll2(expr) expr(); unroll1(expr);
#define unroll3(expr) expr(); unroll2(expr);
#define unroll4(expr) expr(); unroll3(expr);
#define unroll5(expr) expr(); unroll4(expr);
#define unroll6(expr) expr(); unroll5(expr);
#define unroll7(expr) expr(); unroll6(expr);
#define unroll8(expr) expr(); unroll7(expr);
#define unroll(num, expr) unroll##num(expr);

void print() {cout << "Hello World!" << endl;}

int main()
{
    unroll(MAX, print);
    unroll(MAX, print);
    unroll(MAX, print);
    return 0;
}
```

This code results in an error because `unroll(MAX, print)` expands into `unrollMAX(print)`, which is an undefined expression.

What I want is for the preprocessor to see the `MAX` token in the parameter list of `unroll(MAX, print)` and then resolve to `unroll(5, print)` so then it can expand to `unroll5(expr)`.

The following code compiles.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 5

#define unroll1(expr) expr();
#define unroll2(expr) expr(); unroll1(expr);
#define unroll3(expr) expr(); unroll2(expr);
#define unroll4(expr) expr(); unroll3(expr);
#define unroll5(expr) expr(); unroll4(expr);
#define unroll6(expr) expr(); unroll5(expr);
#define unroll7(expr) expr(); unroll6(expr);
#define unroll8(expr) expr(); unroll7(expr);
#define unroll(num, expr) unroll##num(expr);

void print() {cout << "Hello World!" << endl;}

int main()
{
    unroll(5, print);
    unroll(5, print);
    unroll(5, print);
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, the major flaw with this code is that I have to hard-code each call to `unroll` with the number `5`. I might as well just write `unroll5` at that point.

What I need is the ability to define a constant holding the value of `5` so that I can use the name of the constant throughout my program rather than the hard-coded value of `5`. That way, if I decide to change the value of the constant, I don't have to change the parts of the program which use it. This is a really rudimentary programming principle, so it seems like there should be a pretty easy way to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: change `#define MAX 5` to `constexpr auto MAX = 5;`  If you have C++11, and especially if you have C++17 with inline variables, there is no reason to use `#define` to define a constant.  IF you cant use C++11 or new, you can still use `const int MAX = 5;` and it will be a compile time constant.

Comment: Use `#define concat(a, b) a##b` and `#define unroll(num, expr) concat(unroll, num)(expr);`

Comment: Why use macros here? Template here will do this job in nice clean way, For me this sounds like [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Can you explain what kind of problem this macro should solve?

Comment: @Marek R Suppose I want to unroll things other than functions, such as switch statement cases. I can't embed a switch statement case inside of a function or lambda, and then unroll it using C++ templates. I need to use C macros.

Comment: @LoganSchlick: then describe this in more detail using [edit]. There are great solutions which could work like switch statements. If you could describe why you need this macro, then we can propose better approach.  Maybe you are try convert between enumeration and string? Maybe you are building reflections for some classes, maybe .... . This examples are here to show you that your comment still suffers form "XY problem" (less then question, but still).

Answer (score 2):

C macros aren't great at interacting with C++ entities (for example, `constexpr` values which could've been the solution). This problem doesn't exist if you stick to the templates (while possible). In your case you can make the compiler do all the unrolling for you:

```
template<typename F, std::size_t... n>
constexpr void unroll(F f, std::index_sequence<n...>) {
    (..., (void)(n, f())); // repeat n times ignoring the in-between results
}

int main() {
    auto expr = [] { std::cout << "Hello world!\n"; };
    auto constexpr max = 5;
    unroll(expr, std::make_index_sequence<max>{}); // becomes expr(), expr(), expr(), expr(), expr();
}
```

Comment: Yes but I need to use C macros because sometimes I want to unroll things other than functions. For example, what if I want to unroll switch statement cases? Also if I use templates, the compiler doesn't always inline the lambda expression.

Comment: @LoganSchlick unrolling switch-case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46282159/12816539. Not inlining what should be inlined is rather unlikely but if you manage to find a case, you have a backup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108797/can-i-selectively-force-inline-a-function